How would one find the circumference of all circles of a fixed size around a certain offset
I am trying to define a correction factor for a discretization effect, but I am coming across a conceptual error.
The object that I am trying to correct for is defined as
$$
  E(R_{L})= \sum_{i,j \in \Omega} \frac{f(x_i)f(x_j)}{\left( \sum_{k\in \Omega} f(x_k) \right)^2 } \delta(R_L - (x_i - x_j)) 
$$
which is to say, take the value of a function at all pairs of points separated by a distance $R_L$, and normalize by the value of the function at all points within a region $\Omega$.
(For those interested, this is the Energy-Energy Correlator --https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0007)
The issue is that the function can be defined over continuous space, but practical implementation in the context of collection of calorimeter towers with some size $\delta$, there appears to be a problem where the shape of the distribution depends on this size.
To address this issue, I am trying to implement a correction function defined as
$$
\epsilon (R_L, \delta) = \frac{N_{pairs} \in \Omega / N_{pairs} }{\int_{x,y \in \Omega, x^2 + y^2 = R_L} (x,y) / \int_{x \in \Omega, x^2 + y^2 = R_L }(x,y)} \\ 
 N_{pairs} ={(i,j) |\forall x_i \in \Omega, d(x_i, x_j) = R_L }
$$
So for the continuous part of this correction, the problem is to find what percentage of a circle of radius $R_L$ is within a circular region $\Omega$, for all offset centers $x$
The restricted object in the continuous case would be
$$ 
     L=\int_0^{2\pi} d \theta_0 \int_{\delta}^{R_j} d r_0 \int_{\delta \leq r \leq R_j} ds \\
      ds=\sqrt{dr^2 + r^2 d \theta^2} = \frac{2rR_L}{\sqrt{4R_L^2 r_0^2 - \left( R_L^2 +r_0^2 -r^2 \right)^2}} dr \\
$$
Where the variables are defined in the below image.
[EDIT: had a misplaced negative in the line element]
My question is does this make sense? Or is there some better way to approach the efficiency correction?
I keep going back and forth on the normalization as it seems that it would diverge to infinity, hence the introduction of a "minimal size" offset

